# AMD/ATI graphics cards won't work together

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-firepro

I recently took on the task of fixing a stockbroker's computer that is connected to multiple monitors after Windows got bricked on it. My problem is that after I reinstalled Windows I tried to install the drivers for each of the graphics cards. One of them is a Workstation Graphics, Multiview Series AMD FirePro 2450, and the other one is an AMD/ATI FireMV 2250.

If I install the drivers for the FirePro the four monitors that it are attached to it all work and function at the full 1920x1080 resolution, but the other two connected to the FireMV appear as one monitor and only display the basic 1024 screen resolution. But when I install FireMV graphic drivers those two monitors finally work at the 1920x1080 resolution, but the other ones don't even work at all.

I have tried downloading the drivers from the AMD website and also installing the drivers from the disks that originally came with the graphics cards, but I keep getting the same results even when I've tried them on Windows 10, 8.1, and 7. The computer originally had Windows 7 on it. The only thing that I could see that is wrong is that the drivers for the FirePro all say AMD and the ones for the FireMV say ATI on them, so maybe Windows is getting messed up but trying to install the exact same software but one in an AMD folder and also in an ATI folder. I have no idea what is going on or how it was working to begin with, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How many screens are on this PC, reading your wall of text seems to suggest 6? Were these cards using some sort of Crossfire setup originally? Can you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1011182/edit) your question to make it less of a wall of text and easier to read?

Comment: Which drivers did you download, atm there are three sets.
1) Legacy drivers for old old hardware.
2) Catalyst control center for modern stuff up to last week.
3) The replacement for CCC which dropped some older series.
You want drivers for all of these cards, so it will be interesting which driver bundle(s) you used.